# Multiple condition in Join Magento

Tags: magento, join

Can Anyone tell me?

How can i write this type of query in magento
(Multiple condition in on)

```
SELECT Customers.CustomerName, Orders.OrderID
FROM Customers
LEFT JOIN Orders
ON (Customers.CustomerID=Orders.CustomerID and Orders.status = 1)
```

//I know this type

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('module/model_name')->getCollection();
$collection->getSelect()->join( array('table_alias'=>$this->getTable('module/table_name')), 'main_table.foreign_id = table_alias.primary_key', array('table_alias.*'));
```

How can i add multiple condition in JOIN ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer myself, It turnout to be very easy

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('module/model_name')->getCollection();
$collection->getSelect()->join( array('table_alias'=>$this->getTable('module/table_name')), 'main_table.foreign_id = table_alias.primary_key and table_alias.columnname = ".."' , array('table_alias.*'));
```

Comment: where is the condition Orders.status = 1 in this Answer ?

Comment: @Annamalai, table_alias.columnname = "..". you can add any conndition like this. I just gave the example.

Comment: @VaibhavShahu but how do you make it variable? if the "1" from the example is a php variable in my code?

Comment: @peedee 

$collection->getSelect()->join( array('table_alias'=>$this->getTable('module/table_name')), 'main_table.foreign_id = table_alias.primary_key and table_alias.columnname = ".$yourvariable."' , array('table_alias.*'));

Comment: that's what I also ended up with, but it's really ugly